# (EAccessViolation) : Access violation while FreeAndNilChild from Owner (LINUX) LAZARUS PASCAL

Tags: linux, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Im having an acces violation only when hosting a linux server. Windows does not show any issues. This happens when i try to FreeandNilChild Object if OWner , see code. The errors are attached as pictures. Why does this only happen in Linux servers? Am i missing some memory mishandling..could it be GBD version..? Thakns guys appreciated.
TWAObject = class(TObject)

```
destructor TBasePersoneel.Destroy;
 
begin
  FreeAndNilChild(FUser);
  Inherited;
end;
```

then

```
procedure TWAObject.FreeAndNilChild(var obj);
 
Var
  T : TWAObject;
 
begin
  T:=TWAObject(Obj);
  if Assigned(T) and (T.Owner=Self) then
    FreeAndNil(T);
end;
```

Also getting RunError(216) then the EAccessViolation.
The procedure FreeAndNil(var obj); coming from sysinth.inc

Thanks in advance
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looking a the assembly code, it looks like the variable `FUser` contains an invalid value that represents neither `nil` nor a valid object. Maybe under Windows that variable is `nil` or has an invalid value that coincidentally points to some valid address in memory.

Comment: This code smells like a double free waiting to happen. You should look for the other place where you destroy the object. We can't see it here. You'll find it by debugging. Debugging your program is always a good option.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Do you think is there a way to check in the if statement for this "invalid value" as you said that is not pointing to a valid address in memory? thx

Comment: thanks David, Thats what i was suspecting, but cant find anywhere in our project where its freed.

Comment: Put a logging statement in the class destructor. That's what I mean by debugging.

Comment: There is no way to test for an *invalid value* in a memory address. The compiler has no way of knowing what is contained at that address; it just knows whether it is `nil` or not. You need to find all of the places where your variable is being accessed, set breakpoints, and figure out where it's getting free'd inappropriately. We can't do that for you, because you've not provided a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks  for  the  feedbak Ken, turns out I was freeing twice the same object. For some reason in windows, there was allocating ti a correct memory pointer. But in Linux didn't. Thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the feedbak, turns out I was freeing twice the same object. For some reason in windows, there was allocating to a correct memory pointer. But in Linux didn't. Thx guys